# Why must I explicitly write out a list for this function to work?

Tags: python, loops, scipy

I am trying to get a distance metric (silhouette) for a dendrogram while varying one parameter,nclusters_max, with the intention of plotting the result.

Everything works fine if I explicitly write out the int list of numbers I would like to asses:

```
for i in [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]:
    dendrogram, IDs = dendrogram(encoding, n_samples=0, n_clusters_max=i, label_clusters=True, return_clusters=True)
    silhouette = metrics.silhouette_score(encoding, IDs, metric='euclidean')
    print(i, silhouette)
```

Which produces output:

```
4 0.25495732
5 0.27900532
6 0.20914535
7 0.21244033
8 0.21475217
9 0.21835302
10 0.21925814
11 0.20929264
12 0.21342315
```

However, when I try to be more concise (and save effort) by producing the list of numbers with `list(np.arange(4,13))`, i.e:

```
nclusters = list(np.arange(2,14))
for i in nclusters:
    dendrogram, IDs = dendrogram(encoding, n_samples=1, n_clusters_max=i, label_clusters=True, return_clusters=True)
    silhouette = metrics.silhouette_score(encoding, IDs, metric='euclidean')
    print(i, silhouette)
```

I get the error `TypeError: The second argument must be a number`.

nclusters_max must be type(int), but I do not understand the difference between how I produce the values for that variable, and why this could be a problem form my dendrogram function?

Comment: What if you use `n_samples=1` in the first example or `n_samples=0` in the second example?

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating the array of 'int' using

```
nclusters = list(np.arange(2,14))
```

it creates the integers of type `'numpy.int32'`.

You need to type cast it to `'int'` before passing it to your function.

```
n_clusters_max=int(i)
```

Since, in Python the data types are classes hence, here its the difference of class `numpy.int32` and `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the list elements to `Python` **native** type, for example:

```
nclusters = [int(i) for i in np.arange(2, 14)]
```

If the array / list is not too big, just use range:

```
for i in range(2, 14):
```